# JDBI: Is dbi.onDemand more preferred than using dbi.open?

Tags: dbi, dropwizard, jdbi

I am using JDBI with Dropwizard in my application. I have used the dbi.open command to obtain a DAO instance and then use that to run the various queries. In the "finally" block, I use the dao.close() method to close the connection. I have also used dao.inTransaction method to execute multiple DB statements in one single transaction.

While the application has been working for a while without much issues, lately we have seen "PoolExhausted" exception a couple of times, both in Dev and Prod env. I am now wondering if using dbi.onDemand would be a better approach than using dbi.open so that it would eliminate the need to have to call close each time in finally... Could using dbi.open be the reason behind any connection leaks?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what are all the things we are doing in between open and close of the connection.

```
public interface UserDao {
  @SqlQuery("select * from users")
  public List<User> getUsers();

  @SqlUpdate(some query..)
  public void insertUsers(someParam);

}

UserDao dao = dbi.onDemand(UserDao.class);
dao.getUsers();

UserDao dao = dbi.open(UserDao.class);
dao.getUsers();
dao.close();
```

There is no difference between obtaining connection and closing connection here.

```
UserDao dao = dbi.onDemand(UserDao.class);
dao.getUsers();
// calling external service to get some value.
dao.insertUsers();

UserDao dao = dbi.open(UserDao.class);
dao.getUsers();
// calling external service to get some value.
dao.insertUsers();
dao.close();
```

In this example, in onDemand method, connection is opened before getUsers call and closed after that. 
And same happened for insertUsers. During external service call, connection is not held.

In Dbi open method, connection is opened before getUsers and closed after insertUsers. During external service call also connection is held.
If this external calls are costly, then you end up having connection idle for so long and it cant be used for others.

So it always better to use onDemand to get Dao instance.

Comment: what if you call the the first dao1 and second dao2, then after dao2.inserUsers(); you call dao1.inserPeople(); ... before dao2.close() will the dao1 start a new connection ?